# ¿Como extraer filas o columnas de un string en Java?

Tags: java, netbeans, jsp

Les explico: Obtengo un string de respuesta desde una consola de un switch. Esto esta bien y funciona. Se ejecuta un comando que me devuelve una tabla como esta:

```
SwitchPrueba#show port-security
Secure Port  MaxSecureAddr  CurrentAddr  SecurityViolation    SecurityAction
                (Count)       (Count)          (Count)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
      Fa0/1              2            1                  0         Restrict
      Fa0/2              1            0                  0         Restrict
      Fa0/3              1            0                **8**       Restrict
      Fa0/4              1            0                  0         Restrict
      Fa0/5              1            0                  0         Restrict
      Fa0/6              1            0                  0         Restrict
      Fa0/7              1            0                  0         Restrict
      Fa0/8              1            0                  0         Restrict
      Fa0/9              1            0                  0         Restrict
     Fa0/10              1            0                  0         Restrict
     Fa0/11              1            0                  0         Restrict
     Fa0/12              1            0                  0         Restrict
     Fa0/13              1            1                  0         Restrict
     Fa0/14              1            1                  0         Restrict
     Fa0/15              1            0                  0         Restrict
     Fa0/16              1            0                  0         Restrict
     Fa0/17              1            0                  0         Restrict
     Fa0/18              1            1                  0         Restrict
     Fa0/19              1            0                  0         Restrict
     Fa0/20              1            0                  0         Restrict

SwitchPrueba#exit
```

Ahora viene el problema. Necesito ejecutar otro comando que se ejecuta dependiendo de la columna SecurityViolation donde el comando a ejecutar es cuando los valores de esa columna sean mayores a 0. Entonces el comando seria algo asi:

> clear port-security dynamic interface Fa0/3

ya que es el unico mayor a 0

Toda esa tabla lo recibo como un string. Y realmente no se como probar para tratar de obtener linea por linea o columna por columna.

No pongo codigo porque no tengo. Practicamente sería algo asi:

```
String respuesta = "SwitchPrueba#show port-security
Secure Port  MaxSecureAddr  CurrentAddr  SecurityViolation    SecurityAction
                (Count)       (Count)          (Count)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
      Fa0/1              2            1                  0         Restrict
      Fa0/2              1            0                  0         Restrict
      Fa0/3              1            0                **8**       Restrict
      Fa0/4              1            0                  0         Restrict
      Fa0/5              1            0                  0         Restrict
      Fa0/6              1            0                  0         Restrict
      Fa0/7              1            0                  0         Restrict
      Fa0/8              1            0                  0         Restrict
      Fa0/9              1            0                  0         Restrict
     Fa0/10              1            0                  0         Restrict
     Fa0/11              1            0                  0         Restrict
     Fa0/12              1            0                  0         Restrict
     Fa0/13              1            1                  0         Restrict
     Fa0/14              1            1                  0         Restrict
     Fa0/15              1            0                  0         Restrict
     Fa0/16              1            0                  0         Restrict
     Fa0/17              1            0                  0         Restrict
     Fa0/18              1            1                  0         Restrict
     Fa0/19              1            0                  0         Restrict
     Fa0/20              1            0                  0         Restrict

    SwitchPrueba#exit"
```

Comment: Podría ser con BufferedReader y un ciclo while para leer las partes de tu txt

Comment: Puedes hacer un split("\n") para separar por filas y luego, dentro de cada fila, hacer un split("\t"). Ahora sólo te faltará mirar la posición donde está el número a ver si es >0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando lo que expones lo que se podría hacer es tomar la salida de ejecución del primer comando y analizarla desde java. A continuación te dejo un ejemplo que funciona bien con tu caso es decir te imprime la interfaz cuyo security violation es superior a cero. En cada línea de código pongo lo que hago. Este es un ejemplo orientativo (para que veas la idea principal del análisis de los datos), de vos dependerá adaptarlo/mejorarlo de acuerdo a tus necesidades. Yo me base en el ejemplo que pusiste como salida.
Para invocar un comando desde un programa java se utiliza la linea

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar C:/proyectojava/port-security.jar");
```

En el exec tenes que poner el comando que queres ejecutar, en mi caso el jar de ejemplo (port-security.jar) devuelve tu salida por pantalla emulando el proceso que haces. Vos lo tenes que adaptar a lo tuyo.

Este es el ejemplo completo considerando sólo el análisis de la información

```
package programa;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws IOException
    {       
        /*Podes leer de un archivo o bien tomar el input de un proceso. 
          Si lo queres es que tome el input de un proceso hay que usar lo  
         siguiente. 

         En mi ejemplo port-security.jar devuelve la salida por pantalla que pones por pantalla. 
         Puede ser un comando cualquiera el que le pases*/
        BufferedReader reader=null;
        try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar C:/proyectojava/port-security.jar");
        reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));      
        String s = null;
        int contador=0;  
        String interfaz=null;
        String security=null;
        String[] parts=null;
        while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {               

            if (contador==4) // El contador es para comenzar a tomar los datos de donde interesa. Otra opción puede ser quitarle el encabezado antes
            { 
               s=s.trim().replaceAll(" +", " "); //Reemplazamos los espacios por un solo espacio         
               parts=s.split(" "); // Aplicamos el split por el espacio para tener una lista de los diferentes campos del registro
               if (parts.length>3) { //Controlamos las posiciones para que no arroje excepción
                      interfaz=parts[0];    // Seleccionamos el campo interfaz
                      security=parts[3]; //Vamos al campo de security violation
                      security=security.replace("*","");//Le quitamos los asteriscos               
                      if (security.matches("^[1-9]*")) // Si es mayor a cero imprimimos la interfaz y el campo securityviolation
                      {
                          System.out.println(interfaz); //Imprimimos ya que el campo securityviolation es superior a 0
                      }
               }
            }
            else    
                  contador++;
         }
        }
        finally {
            if (reader!=null)
                   reader.close();
        }
    }


}
```

La salida por pantalla es (que es el dato que se estaba intentando conseguir).

```
Fa0/3
```

Saludos y espero sea de tu utilidad.

Comment: +1 s=s.trim().replaceAll(" +", " "); Esta parte hizo que resolviera mi problema, ASi pude obtener las filas y las columnas.